# Correct relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have four tables in database: groups, specialties, lessons, group_lesson. It's structures:

```
groups
    id
    specialty_id
    name
specialties
    id
    name
lessons
    id
    specialty_id
group_lesson (UNIQUE INDEX lesson_id, group_id)
    lesson_id
    group_id
    date
```

My models look like that for now:

```
class Group extends Eloquent {
    public function specialty() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Specialty');
    }
}

class Lesson extends Eloquent {
    public function specialty() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Specialty');
    }
}

class Specialty extends Eloquent {
    public function lessons() {
        return $this->hasMany('Lesson');
    }

    public function groups() {
        return $this->hasMany('Group');
    }
}
```

I need get additional fields in Group model look like that

```
Group - Eloquent model
    name - string
    lessons - collection of Lesson models of Group Specialty
    date - date from group_lesson table
```

I've tried different relationships and combinations, but it's doesn't work. Please help me to write correct relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eager-loading to access relational data through relationships, and can even chain relationships further. As a rule of thumb, if you can draw a path to from 1 model to another through a relationship, you can eagerload all the relevant and relational data for that with chained eager-loads.

[Laravel Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

As an example

```
$speciality_group = Speciality::with('group','lessons')->find($id);
```

Even though you are only getting a single instance of the speciality model, the related data is hasMany, meaning multiple records. You need to loop through these records using a foreach loop to access the relevant data for them, or alternitavely add additional closures in your initial query to load only a single related model.

```
 foreach($speciality_group->group as $group)
    {
      echo $group->name;
    }
```

You will need to do this for both instances where you want to display related information.

Comment: I know that. But I need this one to be working: **Group::with(['lessons'])->find($id);**